# Bootstrap image and text align within columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

By using Bootstrap, I'm trying to make rows of 3 images and text on their right. If browsing with a mobile (small) device, I want just one image per row with text on right. The images can be of different sizes, but I want them shown in the same size (inline style now).
Currently it looks ok on large devices, but when shrinking viewport, the wrapping is off. Instead of all columns coming under one another at one point, they are wrapping wrongly. If I remove the "pull left" on image, they wrap correctly but the text is then below image. How can I manage to do what I want here?

My current html:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" class="pull-left img-rounded" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
    <h3>Header 1</h3>
    <p>Text 1 is cool text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="pull-left img-rounded" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
    <h3>Header 2</h3>
    <p>Text 2 is also cool text</p>
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/" class="pull-left img-rounded" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
    <h3>Header 3</h3>
    <p>Text 3 is also very cool text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dakssjbd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" class="img-rounded col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h3>Header 1</h3>
         <p>Text 1 is cool text</p>
      </div>   
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-rounded col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h3>Header 2</h3>
          <p>Text 2 is also cool text</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/" class="img-rounded col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>Header 3</h3>
        <p>Text 3 is also very cool text</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this is not it. If you try to shrink the viewport little by little, you see a very weird wrapping situation at one point, and when narrow enough they wrap under each other. The text should always be to the right of image. Both in desktop and mobile. But on mobile only one image per row.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I have to wrap my column in another div of class clearfix:

```
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="clearfix content-heading">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" class="pull-left img-rounded" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
    <h3>Header 1</h3>
    <p>Text 1 is cool text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="clearfix content-heading">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="pull-left img-rounded" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
    <h3>Header 2</h3>
    <p>Text 2 is also cool text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="clearfix content-heading">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/" class="pull-left img-rounded" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
    <h3>Header 3</h3>
    <p>Text 3 is also very cool text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dakssjbd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for bootstrap column breakpoints and still looking for some stuff try to using bootstrap media breakpoints.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 row1" >
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" class="pull-left img-rounded" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
      <h3>Header 1</h3>
      <p>Text 1 is cool text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 row2">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="pull-left img-rounded" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
      <h3>Header 2</h3>
      <p>Text 2 is also cool text</p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 row3">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/" class="pull-left img-rounded" style="margin-right:10px;width:100px;height:100px;">
      <h3>Header 3</h3>
      <p>Text 3 is also very cool text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS USING MEDIA BREAKPOINTS:
**using max-width**

```
<style type="text/css">

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES*/
       body{
        background-color: black;
       }
       .row2{
          display: none;
       }
       .row3{
          display:none;
       }

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES*/
       body{
        background-color: blue;
       }
       .row3{
          display:none;
       }
    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
         /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES| SET HERE WHAT YOU NEED TO HIDE OR ANYTHING*/
       body{
        background-color: green;
       }
    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens 
      USE DEFAULT
    */

</style>
```

**using min-width**

```
<style type="text/css">

        /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
        @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
            /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES*/
           body{
            background-color: black;
           }

        }

        /* Small Devices, Tablets */
        @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
            /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES*/
           body{
            background-color: blue;
           }
        }

        /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
        @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
             /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES| SET HERE WHAT YOU NEED TO HIDE OR ANYTHING*/
           body{
            background-color: green;
           }
        }

        /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
        @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
            /* YOUR CODE HERE*/
        }
    </style>
```